# Receive enum as value in function

Tags: java, enums

I have few constants I need to track and each constant has multiple values, so I have created few enums to avoid remembering what each Id reprezents, and have declared them like this

SomeName is located in **package com.aaa.bbb.ccc.dddd**

```
package com.aaa.bbb.ccc.dddd;

public enum SomeName{
    SKILL1(1, "value1-1", "value1-2"),
    SKILL2(2, "value2-1", "value2-2"),
    SKILL3(3, "value3-1", "value3-2");

    private final int skillId;
    private final String value1;
    private final String value2;

    private SomeName(int id, String value1, String value2){
        this.skillId = id;
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;   
    }
}
```

This enum will not have more than these three values defined. Now I need to define my method like this

This method is declared inside a class defined in **package com.aaa.eee.fff**

```
package com.aaa.eee.fff;
import com.aaa.bbb.ccc.dddd.SomeName;

public class SomeClass {
    public SomeName function(SomeName param){
        //some work
    }
}
```

but I always get an error `cannot find symbol class SomeName`

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Not possible to tell from this.  Are these all in the same file?  If so will need to see more code and build command.

Comment: No, Enum declaration and function that receives it as parameter are not in same file

Comment: Post the part where your code uses `SomeConstant` - you haven't shown us where this error message could be getting `SomeConstant` from. Or is it that you're missing the `import` statement?

Comment: Your error message mentions `SomeConstant` but presumably, with your edits, it should now mention `SomeName` instead I assume?

Comment: yep, forgot to edit it, thanks

Comment: @D.L How are you compiling your code? I fear that you might be doing it from the wrong location.

Comment: i copy pasted your code in the named packages, and i dont get any compiler errors. i use eclipse, could be a problem with intellij idea or you might be doing something wrong in other parts of the code which you are not showin here

Comment: @D.L you might consider trying the same thing that chaitanya10 did; create the fake packages and copy the code you posted there to see if it works for you.  If that does indeed work, the problem is likely in some discrepancy between your real code and the version with fake names that you posted.

Comment: yep, thanks guys, it has something to do with intellij, I have moved the class from one package to another earlier today and intellij automatically updated all imports but for whatever reason it it did not recompile these classes, rebuilding project instead of debugging it solved the problem